# Assembly imports

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
  private void WheelResize(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
```

The compiler gives me this error:

```
 The type or namespace name 'MouseWheelEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The problem is that it works fine with `MouseButtonEventArgs`, which is apparently in the same assembly and namespace. What gives?

Comment: try the full qualified name! it's a strange err.

Comment: MouseButtonEventArgs (which works) and MouseWheelEventArgs (which) doesn't, are being used in the same source file? Is MouseButtonEventArgs used with the fully qualified name (that would be System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)? If so, also fully qualify MouseWheelEventArgs or add a using statement for the System.Windows.Input namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you didn't add required assemblies to your project. Add `PresentationCore.dll` to your projects's references, then use namespace:

```
using System.Windows.Input
```

Comment: Or `System.Windows.dll` if using silverlight.

Comment: It was included in every WPF project by default.